# number of digits common between 2 binary numbers

Tags: c, recursion, binary

I was writing a program that counts the number of bits in common between the two binary representations of the given numbers. The code I have written is:

```
int common_bits(int a, int b) {


static long binaryNo1,binaryNo2,remainder1,remainder2,factor = 1;

if(a!= 0&&b!=0){

     remainder1 = a % 2;
     binaryNo1 = remainder1 * factor;
     remainder2 = b % 2;
     binaryNo2 = remainder2 * factor;
     factor = factor * 10;
     if (binaryNo2==binaryNo1)
     {
         int count=0;
         count++;

     }
    common_bits(a/2,b/2);
}

        return 0;



}
```

I have been facing error with this could anyone explain why and tell me how to correct it.

An example of how this works is: 13 (1101 in binary) and 7 (111 in binary) have 2 bits in common

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you only counting where both numbers have a `1`?  Or also where they both have `0`?  What about leading zeros?

Comment: Also, everything about your code is more complicated than it needs to be.  You can just compare `remainder1` to `remainder2`.

Comment: No  I am Ignoring leading zeros and consider the number zero to have a single bit representation of 0.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes you are right, comparing those is enough- I don't think that is the source of the issue. thanks i will make the change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's fix your program: your code does not return anything after the recursive invocation, multiplies by a factor that is not necessary, uses a factor of 10<sup>k</sup> instead of 2<sup>k</sup>, and uses recursion that is not necessary. The fix is reasonably simple:

```
remainder1 = a % 2;
remainder2 = b % 2;
int count = 0;
if (remainder1 == remainder2) {
    count++;
}
return count + common_bits(a/2, b/2);
```

Comment: Except that using the remainder operator is broken, because it gives three values (-1, 0, 1) when there should be only two possibilities.

Comment: Thanks loads! I really regret not seeing through the issue

Comment: @BenVoigt You are right, `%` is used with an implicit assumption that the numbers are positive.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to build the numeric value of treating the binary string of digits as if they were decimal digits, which is where just about all your problems are coming in.  Well, it's not actually that idea causing your problems, but the poor style of the code you used to try to implement the idea.  `static` variables are bad, particularly with recursion.  Failing to return a value is bad too.

This is enough:

```
int common_bits(int a, int b)
{
    if (a == 0) return 0;
    if (b == 0) return 0;
    return ((a&1) == (b&1)) + common_bits(a/2, b/2);
}
```

It works because `a&1` gets the lowest bit of `a`, and `==` evaluates to one when the two operands are equal, zero otherwise.

Or you could use XNOR, sometimes also called bitwise EQV:

```
return ((a^~b)&1) + common_bits(a/2, b/2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really like the way you cut down the code- thats something I wish to develop.

Comment: @L887: Well, it's clear you didn't mean to ignore the return value of the recursive call.  Or throw away `count` without using it.